# Monkeyrunner.sleep(5) Not working

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner

MonkeyRunner.sleep (5) gives an error when I type. I wonder why I wrote no problem 3?

Google translate

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice, MonkeyImage
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
device.touch(112, 149, "DOWN_AND_UP")
MonkeyRunner.sleep(5)
device.touch(139, 173, "DOWN_AND_UP")
```

> ```
> 31019 13:33:34.222:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Error se
> nding touch event: 139 153 DOWN_AND_UP
> 131019 13:33:34.222:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]java.net.
> SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
> 131019 13:33:34.222:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.
> net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
> 131019 13:33:34.222:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.
> net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
> 131019 13:33:34.222:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.
> net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
> 131019 13:33:34.222:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.n
> io.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

use as below in you code:-

```
device.touch(112, 149, "MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP")
MonkeyRunner.sleep(5)
device.touch(139, 173, "MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP")
```

And for sleep you can use below method also!

try:-

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```